# Can you query recently added objects without calling SubmitChanges?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Without getting into the details of my application I am curious if this is even possible in linq-to-sql or not.

Can I write a LINQ statement to look at both the **records in the database** and **records that have been added recently using the InsertOnSubmit method calls**?  I am trying to write an **Exists** method and it only seems to work if I have called **SubmitChanges** method.  So it appears to only be looking at the records in the database and not the ones that are in memory.

Is the only way to accomplish this is check the database first (using LINQ) then check the changeset (using GetChangeset) inserts collection?

I realize linq-to-sql will not optimize my SQL into one statement but to me the code would be cleaner with one **SubmitChanges** call outside of my loop.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I decided to keep my code the way it was where I basically SubmitChanges right after adding a record to one of the two tables.  This way my Exists LINQ query will always work as expected.  It was easier to do that then try and include both the records from the database and the records about to be saved to the database.  It's unfortunate that there isn't an easier way to handle this.  I just assumed when I added a record using **InsertOnSubmit** it would be included when I did my LINQ queries but **now I know otherwise**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, what you want is not possible using just one simple Linq-to-Sql query. You'll have to work around it, and it's difficult to do this in a generic way.

However, if you only want to concatenate the results from the DB and the entities added to the DataContext, how about something like this:

Instead of:

```
db.Orders.Where (o => o.OrderDate > DateTime.Now);
```

You write:

```
// Or put the method on DataContext as an extension method
var queryFunc = GetCombinedQuery (db, d => d.Orders, os => os.Where (o => o.OrderDate > DateTime.Now));
```

With the following helper:

```
IQueryable<TResult> GetCombinedQuery<T, TResult> (DataContext dataContext, Func<DataContext, IQueryable<T>> dbQueryableProvider, Func<IQueryable<T>, IQueryable<TResult>> queryProvider)
{
  var dbDataSource = dbQueryableProvider (dataContext);
  var dbQuery = queryProvider (dbDataSource);
  var inMemorySource = dataContext.GetObjectStateEntries (EntityState.Added).Select (e => e.Entity).OfType<T>();
  var inMemoryQuery = queryProvider (inMemorySource);
  return dbQuery.Concat (inMemoryQuery);
}
```

Comment: I marked your question as the answer because it is the closest to the answer I was looking for even though I didn't use it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Can I write a LINQ statement to look at both the records in the
>   database and records that have been added recently using the
>   InsertOnSubmit method calls?

No, if you want it out of the box.

Bear in mind that with Linq-to-SQL an sql select statement is being sent to the database server and getting executed *there*.

The Entity-Framework maintains a state for each object that it handles in order to track changes.

Given that fact, you can easily query for added-state objects in your `ObjectContect`:

```
using(var context = new yourDataContext())
{
  var recentlyAddedObjects = context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added);

  var addedObjects = recentlyAddedObjects.Select(entry => entry.Entity)
                    .OfType<ResourceType>().ToList();
}
```

And don't forget to change the `ResourceType` type to your real `Type`.

A good resource to read about object states would be: [Object States and Change-Tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386982.aspx)

Comment: Will this work in linq-to-sql?  The code you are suggesting appears to be linq-to-entities not linq-to-sql.  Also I would like to find a way to query both recently added objects (in-memory) and the ones that already exist in the database.  I was hoping it was just a context configuration option I am missing or something.

Comment: Sure, read this: [Object States and Change-Tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386982.aspx)

Comment: Out of the box getting in-memory objects along with in-database objects is impossible without a programmatic intervention - Bear in mind that with Linq-to-SQL a select statement is being sent to the database server and get executed there.